# CSS media query for zoom capable devices

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

When the screen size allows it, my menu bar is fixed on the left side of the page.

```
@media (min-width: 900px) {
    #menu {
        position: fixed;
    }
}
```

But when viewed on a smartphone for example, using the pinch zoom will make the menu zoom with the content and collide with the rest of the page. Can this be avoided with something like a `@media zoom-capable` kind of query?

Clarification: What I'm after is this - menu is fixed on computer screens but normal/default on screens that allow finger zooming. Using cmd plus/minus to enlarge the page on a desktop computer isn't a problem.

Comment: I think the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223866/media-queries-for-different-zoom-levels-of-browser will help you.

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom Hmmm, not quite. I've tried to clarify my question.

Comment: Solved temporarily with `@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #menu {
        position: fixed;
    }`
But it's not really about screen size, it's about the way the screen behaves...
}