# iPad zoom in detact other media query

Tags: html, css

In iPad landscape mode I use 1024 media query and for portrait mode I use 768 media query.

When I zoom in landscape 1024 mode it detects portrait 768 media query. Why is it changing media query when I zoom (and after zoom it does not zoom out automatically to actual size, it freezes on that media query)?

I have used in header:

```
meta name="view port" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no"
```

Comment: I'm sure Googling this will get you answers. This looks good for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223866/media-queries-for-different-zoom-levels-of-browser

Comment: @Pekka웃 Then this question is a duplicate, and you should flag it as such.

Comment: @cybermonkey I'm not sure I understand the OP's question well enough to determine whether it's a dupe or not.

Comment: this is not working for me frnd, anyways thnx for help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to fix minor grammar mistakes and to improve formatting - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide additional information that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!