# media query for 25%, 33% and 50% zoom level

Tags: css

We added media query for different levels of zoom as per screen size, Like

```
 @media (max-width: 992px)

 @media (max-width: 1200px)

 @media (max-width:1920px)

 @media (max-width:1500px)
```

But when we do zoom levels to 25% or 33% or 50% then our layout design breaks. Is there any media query for these levels of zoom?

As we searched on google, all media queries available for above 50% zoom, Not for 33% or 25% zoom, like in this example [Media Queries for Different zoom Levels of Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223866/media-queries-for-different-zoom-levels-of-browser)

this example is for max zoom levels not for minimum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media Queries for Different zoom Levels of Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223866/media-queries-for-different-zoom-levels-of-browser)

Comment: This is different, We updated our question, please have a look

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer
For 50% zoom we can use this media query

```
 @media (min-width:2052px) and (max-width:2732px)
 {

 }
```

and for 33% zoom we can use this

```
 @media (min-width:2733px) and (max-width:4102px) 
 {

 }
```

and for 25% zoom, we can use this media query

```
 @media (min-width:4103px) and (max-width:5464px)
 {

 }
```