# Handling resolution which is zoomed in to 150% via css

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a web page which has a header section, this header section contains Name, menu items on next lines.
[image]

i have added padding on top of name and above,below menu items.
it works perfectly fine for most of the system. 
However there are systems (windows 10) which is scaled to 150% in display settings. 
Now since i am using padding in px the space is getting increased more than expected in those system.
how can i write custom code for these scenerios where i am not aware of default scale level in different screen size ?

Comment: Media queries work with browser zoom: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223866/media-queries-for-different-zoom-levels-of-browser

Comment: is that zoomed using css or zoomed using browser or zoomed using windows?  That's 3 very different scenarios and your question is quite ambiguous as to which is causing the zoom

Comment: I agree, but that holds valid for Browser zoom, i am talking about scaling which is done at OS level, in such case the content are zoomed at 150%. If in inspect element i zoom my 1080p screen to 150%, it comes around 826p*550p, at this resolution also my screen looks good, but in reality when i see the content on those screen it looks totally different. when i set browser zoom level to 90% everything falls back to its place.

Comment: @pete those laptops are of 1080p resoltion which are zoomed to 150%(recommended) by OS under display settings.

Comment: Browser Zoom is kinda like responsive: The page gets bigger, but the site width gets smaller. So if you look at a page in 200% browser zoom, it should about be the same as looking at it with a phone (or the same as resizing your desktop browser). OS zoom is something completely different and varies based on Browser and OS. Edit: seems to be possible with JS but it's really really messy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers

Comment: @elveti I totally agree!!! i could find a single good solution to resolve this issue, i tried using VH,% and px but none of them work

Comment: hmmm not sure how you would detect os level zooming, how about using rem - that way the padding is based on the font size (which should change depending on the zoom?)