# Can media queries respond to user initiated zooming?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've included a very basic snippet, which includes a row of flex items that collapses a column when the [viewport width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width) is less than 768px. If you open the snippet full page and then open the dev tools you can resize the viewport and see this happens as expected.

However, if you set the viewport with to something like 780px and zoom in just a bit (shift + click and drag on Chrome) the row does not collapse into a column like it does when you resize the screen itself. Is it possible to alter the layout in response to user initiated zooming in a trivial way (i.e. HTML, CSS no JS)? I am aware of media queries responding to zoom if the zoom level is set in `em`, but that requires a page reload which is cumbersome and makes for pretty bad UX.

[Here is a loom video showing what I mean](https://www.loom.com/share/581df0a1ae1e4522856a432b516631fd).

```css
.flex-responsive {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .flex-responsive {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-responsive'>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if you set the viewport with to something like 780px` are you talking about changing the media query here ? if yes then i can't reproduce the problem you're talking about

Comment: oops no I'm sorry, I'm talking about setting the simulated device width in dev tools

Comment: the issue you're talking about is `(shift + click and drag on Chrome)` to zoom, that feature doesn't trigger media queries because it's meant to enlarge portions of the page specially designated for people with low vision, imagine someone trying to zoom in on something then the media query kicks in and suddenly everything changed, talking about a bad UX

Comment: @ZohirSalak I'm not sure what you mean to say here, it's just a simulated pinch zoom. It doesn't work on a real mobile device either. I added a link to a short video showing what I'm describing

Comment: This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22247258/3684265) simply says your best bet is to create media queries that can be used for multiple devices taking the zoom into consideration.

Comment: `(shift + click and drag on Chrome)` is the pinch zoom on mobile devices, you have no control over that even with JS

Comment: @ZohirSalak good thing I'm not trying to control the user's zoom then...

Comment: According to what you said, the column doesn't collapse when you zoom in with `(shift + click and drag on Chrome)` it's because the pinch zoom, the `viewport` isn't touched

Comment: even if that were true (and I don't think it is since zooming is enabled and configured via `meta name="viewport" content="...`) it's not particularly helpful, I'm not asking "why doesn't this work" I'm asking "is this thing possible"

Comment: It's Not­­­­­­­

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak he has been saying that there is no way to interact with that kind of zoom in any way and if you could it would be bad ux.

Comment: @ZohirSalak do you have any reference for that knowledge or are you just insisting something is true when you don't actually know? Saying "It's Not" is even less helpful than what you've been doing

Comment: @ivan ? I'm not sure how that can be possible when there are a wealth of questions discussing how to **prevent** pinch zoom from altering layouts, there must be some way to leverage that behavior, and if there isn't then please point me to some reference