# How to make responsive when zoomed in and zoomed out. It should be same

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a css set for screen size 125% but when I zoom in for 150% the content of the html overflows.

```
.test-width{
    width: 370px;
}
.test-padding {
   padding-left: 0px;
}
.colwidth {
   width: 150%;
}

<div class="colWidth test-padding">
     <div class="card-header cardHeaderStyle test-width">
         <h4 class="justify-cardheader-center">Base Cohort</h4>
      </div>
</div>
```

When I zoom in or zoom out the content should be responsive

Comment: you have to use media queries and make your web page resonsive. read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223866/media-queries-for-different-zoom-levels-of-browser

Comment: It works but when I resize the window size it again moves out of the screen.