# Scale element when zoom - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an scrollbar which height is 31.25em. Now this looks fine as it is on screen but if I zoom in via the web browser like from 100% to 110%, the scroll bar seems to increase in size. My question is how to scale the scroll bar so that it looks correct after zoom?

```
.scrollText{

   max-height: 31.25em;
   overflow: auto;
   padding-right: 1em;
   padding-bottom: 2em;
 }
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223866/media-queries-for-different-zoom-levels-of-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Changing scroll bar size with media queries and scrollbar webkit element

> Basic Introduction

Firstly on most browsers the scroll bar stays the same size when zooming in. However if you want to change you scroll-bar size you can probably use media queries and the scrollbar CSS element to make the scroll-bar size decrease as you zoom in.

> Proposed solution

You can probably use something like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:150px) and (max-width:600px){
   body::-webkit-scrollbar {
     width: 1em;
   }
}
```

> Other resources

See [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/) for further reading on scroll bar size and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) for more info on media queries